# Uploading my code gets an error : permission denied on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, ubuntu

I have faced this problem for few years ago and I solved it on Ubuntu 14.04 but I don't know why my solution doesn't work right now on Ubuntu 16.04

The Error :

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied

I'm using the same solution from [The guide](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload)

Here what I've done :

> ls -l /dev/ttyACM* 
>   
>  from the result : The owner is "root" and the group with access is " dialout 
>   
> Then I applied 
>   
>   sudo usermod -a -G dialout UserName 
>   sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0 
>  Finally logged out and logged in .

After all should be worked but  I still have the same Error , it doesn't work at all , I removed the software and re-installed it didn't work as well

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove modemmanager`

Comment: Are you sure with ttyACM0? My Arduinos always show up as ttyUSB0

Comment: @chrisl Yes I'm sure . Any help ?

Comment: @Majenko still ! , didn't solve it

Comment: @chrisl Real Arduinos with an ATMega for the USB use CDC/ACM, so appear as ttyACMx. Clones that use other chips, or ancient Arduinos with an FT232 appear as ttyUSBx.

Comment: Did you install the snap app of the Arduino IDE? This is known to not work properly in many cases.

Comment: @oh.dae.su No I have never installed it !

Comment: Re-check the permissions on the device node now you have logged out etc. Some useful commands: `stat /dev/ttyACM0` - check the first "Access:" line.  `sudo fuser /dev/ttyACM0` - list processes that are using the device node.

Comment: @Majenko When I try to see " sudo fuser ... " that shows " Specified filename /dev/ttyACM0 does not exist. " What does it mean ?

Comment: Is the board plugged in at the time you run the command?

Comment: @Majenko Yes it is, I unplugged it and plugged back again to try then run the command but the command show nothing actually just press Enter then I got nothing " no result " , and the error still on Arduino software

Comment: If it returns nothing then nothing is locking the device. That's good. How about the first Access: line from the stat command?

Comment: @Majenko That return " (0660/crw-rw----)  Uid: ( 1001/     moh)   Gid: ( 1001/     moh) "
Note : moh is the user , and it's already member of dialout "the group with access" , what do you think ?

Comment: How about if you type `echo foo > /dev/ttyACM0` - does that return anything?

Comment: Finally ! I got it , it works now ! Thank you so much , appreciate your help

Comment: What did you do to make it work?